# Sorting by list column

Tags: python

I have this list like this:

```
list1 = [["A",5,2,8,3],["B",9,5,1,5]]
```

And I'm trying to sort it by the second column. I would expect list1 to then be

```
[["B",9,5,1,5],["A",5,2,8,3]]
```

Because 9 is greater than 5 right? I'm using

```
sorted(lis1, key=lambda a : a[1])
```

however it doesn't sort it; it just remains as it was before. Why isn't this working?

Comment: It sorts in ascending order by default. Add the argument `reverse=True` to your `sorted` function to generate the desired output

Answer (score 2):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> **Return** a new sorted list from the items in iterable

It does *not* sort in place.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reverse it:

```
list1 = [["A",5,2,8,3],["B",9,5,1,5]]
list1 = sorted(list1, key=lambda a : a[1], reverse=True)
print(list1)
# outputs [["B",9,5,1,5],["A",5,2,8,3]]
```

9>5, so it comes afterwards, unless you reverse.

Comment: Tried that and it still has not changed..

Comment: Strange... when I copy the above code and run it it works

Comment: Are you sure you're doing: `list1 = sorted(list1, key=lambda a : a[1], reverse=True)`? `sorted` doesn't modify the list, it returns a modified list...

Comment: You can also do:  `list1.sort(key=lambda a : a[1], reverse=True)` and it will modify `list1` so that you don't need to reassign to it.

Comment: Ahah! Yes that works now I added list1 = before it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using operator.itemgetter() function:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list1 = [["A",5,2,8,3],["B",9,5,1,5],["C",1,2,8,3]]

print(sorted(list1, key=itemgetter(1)))
print(sorted(list1, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
[['C', 1, 2, 8, 3], ['A', 5, 2, 8, 3], ['B', 9, 5, 1, 5]]
[['B', 9, 5, 1, 5], ['A', 5, 2, 8, 3], ['C', 1, 2, 8, 3]]
```